# SQL Join that finds non matches

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, left-join

I have two tables "SellerDetails" and "ANL" and both have key fields of "Seller Ref No" and "Sales Year".

[image]

This giving me where there is a match on Seller Ref No where the Sales Year is "20" and the Department is "Remote Sales"

```
SELECT si.[Seller Ref No] FROM dbo.SellerDetails AS si, dbo.ANL AS a
WHERE si.[Seller Ref No] = a.[Seller Ref No]
AND si.Department = 'Remote Sales'
AND si.[Sales Year] = '20';
```

But how do I find out the records that are in "SellerDetails" **but NOT** in "ANL" where the Sales Year is "20" and the Department is "Remote Sales"?  I have tried this but it returns a quantity much larger than I expect.  I have also tried changing '=' to '<>' but that provided a worse result

```
SELECT si.[Seller Ref No]
FROM dbo.SellerDetails AS si
LEFT JOIN dbo.ANL AS a ON (si.[Seller Ref No] = a.[Seller Ref No])
WHERE si.Department = 'Remote sales'
AND si.[Sales Year] = '20';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from dbo.SellerDetails s
where 
    s.Department = 'Remote Sales'
    and s.[Sales Year] = 20
    and not exists (select 1 from dbo.ANL a where a.[Seller Ref No] = s.[Seller Ref No])
```

It is unclear whether you want to use `[Sales Year]` as a correlation condition too: it is present in both tables, but your query does not use that relation. If you want it, then:

```
select s.*
from dbo.SellerDetails s
where 
    s.Department = 'Remote Sales'
    and s.[Sales Year] = 20
    and not exists (select 1 from dbo.ANL a where a.[Seller Ref No] = s.[Seller Ref No] and a.[Sales Year] = s.[Sales Year])
```

Side note: here is the query you presumably wanted to write, using a `left join`:

```
SELECT si.[Seller Ref No]
FROM dbo.SellerDetails AS si
LEFT JOIN dbo.ANL AS a ON si.[Seller Ref No] = a.[Seller Ref No]
WHERE 
    si.Department = 'Remote sales'
    AND si.[Sales Year] = '20'
    AND a.[Seller Ref No] IS NULL
```

The last condition in the `WHERE` clause filters out matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT si.[Seller Ref No]
FROM dbo.[SellerDetails] AS   si
LEFT JOIN dbo.[ANL] AS a ON   si.[Seller Ref No] = a.[Seller Ref No]
                     AND   si.[Department] = 'Remote sales'
                     AND   si.[Sales Year] = '20'
Where a.[Seller Ref No] is null
```